# fetching data from multiple tables in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp and trying my best to implement queries in cakephp. 
I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM question join question_topic on question.question_id=question_topic.question_id join topic on topic.topic_id=question_topic.topic_id join user_topic on user_topic.topic_id=topic.topic_id where user_topic .user_id=10
```

I need this in cakephp.

What I have tried is this

```
$this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
              'User',
              'UserInfo.UserTopic'=>array(
                       'conditions'=>array('UserTopic.user_id'=>10)
                  ),
              'QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer','Answer.UserInfo'

            ),


           'order' => 'rand()',
            'recursive' => 0
        ));
```

But the query is not giving me a right results. Could you please take a look.

**Question.php**

```
class Question extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'question';
    public $primaryKey = 'question_id';


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'fields' => array('User.user_id','User.email','User.active')

        ),
        'UserInfo' => array(
            'className' => 'UserInfo',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',


        )
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Answer' => array(
            'className' => 'Answer',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',


        ),

        'QuestionAndTopic' => array(
            'className' => 'QuestionAndTopic',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
     )
  );

  public function latestQuestions(){
         $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(

            'contain' => array(
              'User',
              'UserInfo.UserTopic'=>array(
                       'conditions'=>array('UserTopic.user_id'=>10)
                  ),
              'QuestionAndTopic.Topic','UpVoteQuestion','Answer','Answer.UserInfo'

            ),


           'order' => 'rand()',
            'recursive' => 0
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysql query it will works as like as cakephp query

```
$this->Behaviors->query('SELECT * FROM question join question_topic on question.question_id=question_topic.question_id join topic on topic.topic_id=question_topic.topic_id join user_topic on user_topic.topic_id=topic.topic_id where user_topic .user_id=10');
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer  [this link](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-write-a-join-query-across-multiple-tables-in-CakePHP/4049/)

```
    $options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'books_tags',
        'alias' => 'BooksTag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Book.id = BooksTag.book_id'
        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'tags',
        'alias' => 'Tag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'BooksTag.tag_id = Tag.id'
        )
    )
);
$options['conditions'] = array(
    'Tag.tag' => 'Novel'
);
$books = $Book->find('all', $options);
```

make changes as per you table and fields.hope this helps.